# How to pass host environment variable to provisioning script

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

I have the following line in my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provisioning/myscript.sh"
```

I would like to toggle running that script based on an environment variable being set in the host (which may not be present). If the value is present and equals `true` I want the script skipped, otherwise it should run e.g.

```
if [ ENV[SKIP_MY_SCRIPT] != 'true' ]
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provisioning/myscript.sh"
end
```

Or is there a better way (e.g. pass env into the script somehow)?

Answer (score 0):

As Vagrantfile is mainly a ruby script, there's no bad to have conditional statement in the file.

To answer the specific question *How to pass host environment variable to provisioning script* (can help for other use cases) you can pass arguments like

```
  username = `whoami`.chomp
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "provisioning/config-git.sh", args: "#{username}"
```

and in your script, you read as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
username=$1
```